# product_cat image url from database

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to get the image url of the product categories.

I got all product categories using:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy='product_cat')
```

I found that the images are stored as posts with post_type = 'attachment', but I can't find the connection between those and the product categories.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection was in wp_termmeta. The term_id has a meta_key = 'thumbnail_id' and the meta_value is the post_id containing the url of the image.